# Log warning on jitsi meet linux ubuntu

Tags: webrtc, sctp, jitsi

In the jvb.log I have this warning on more rows:

*"Got sctp association state update: 1
sctp is now up.  was ready? false"*

It's normal? Why?

Have you a solution for clean this message?
Thanks

Comment: Not aware of this issue, but I would suggest for quicker response post it in jitsi community forums. - https://community.jitsi.org/

Comment: thanks for your response and suggest.